# Github pages showing old code

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I have a rudimentary understanding of Github: I know how to create, add, commit, push and clone repositories. I've also started exploring Github pages to host my projects. My latest project I started in March and pushed it to a gh-page. I have since then refractored and improved the code and made quite a few changes. On my local server the changes are shown but after pushing to Github and making a new gh-page several times, I still see the old project.

Could someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it shows you `non-fast-forward updates were rejected`, that means your local and remote repository are out of sync because you or someone else made changes to the upstream repo and this could be a possible cause of your problem.

Try to `fetch` and then `rebase` or just use `pull --rebase` command.

Source: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-non-fast-forward-errors

If this isn't the problem, does it show errors when pushing? And does you project have multiple branches?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try your recommendations when I am on my home machine. I also spoke to Github and looking at my commits I see only one commit which was my first commit, so I think I didn't properly push the new commits.